# Should I use singleton in my JFrames?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, singleton

In my java program, I have various `JFrame` windows.

My main frame can open all the other frames. I want to be able to run only one instance each frame. I want also to be able to pass arguments to the frame.

Should I use Singleton to initiate the class and then pass the arguments? Or is there a better way?

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: Ideally each class would be completely isolated from everything else, injecting those members (your singleton) into the classes that need it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since this is not really a coding problem it is difficult to give you a precise answer to your problem.

Since you specifically say *I want to be able to run only one instance of each Jframe*, I would always advise on using singletons. They are very easy to code and will allow you to access the JFrames from within multiple classes.